# How do I get data into a constructor from two different loops

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have a homework assignment to Create an app that allows users to enter information about a collection of board games. The data entered by the user will be stored/accessed through a class. The steps I am given are to create the class, named BoardGame, for storing a collection of (analog or non-digital) board games with 8 fields. I then make a constructor that stores ONLY the first three fields. Then, for all fields, I create individual get and set methods, along with a toString method to print all the data for all the fields. Then within the main method there are 3 parts. Part 1, create an array called boardGames that has an array size of 4 (Right now I just have it set to 1 for testing). Create a loop to ONLY get the first three pieces of information. Part 2. AFTER the three basic pieces of the board game have been entered by the user, create a second loop to get the remaining five information from the user. Part 3. Once all the remaining data has been entered and stored by the user, create a third loop to print all the data in the array using the toString method (from the BoardGame class) for each object.

I think everything in BoardGame is set up correctly. I can also get Either step 1 or step 2 working with step 3. the issue is that I can't get step 1 AND step 2 to work at the same time. the Array either has the first 3 pieces of info or the last 5 pieces

I have tried making multiple constructors. I have tried a bunch of stuff that are probably all rookie errors XD

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        BoardGame[] boardGame = new BoardGame[1];

        // Loop for first three peices of info
        for (int i = 0; i < boardGame.length; i++) {

            String gameName, publisherName, yearPublished;

            System.out.print("What is the name of the board game? ");
            gameName = scnr.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Publisher name? ");
            publisherName = scnr.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Year published? ");
            yearPublished = scnr.nextLine();

            boardGame[i] = new BoardGame (gameName, publisherName, yearPublished);

        }

        // Loop for remaining peices of info
        for (int i = 0; i < boardGame.length; i++) {
            String genre;
            double price;
            int minPlayerNum, maxPlayerNum, playTime;

            System.out.print("How much does " + boardGame[i].getGameName() + " cost? ");
            price = scnr.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("What is the minimum number of players for " + boardGame[i].getGameName() + "? ");
            minPlayerNum = scnr.nextInt();

            System.out.print("What is the maximum number of players for " + boardGame[i].getGameName() + "? ");
            maxPlayerNum = scnr.nextInt();

            System.out.print("What is the game genre? ");
            scnr.nextLine();
            genre = scnr.nextLine();

            System.out.print("How long on average does it take to play " + boardGame[i].getGameName() + " (in minutes)? ");
            playTime = scnr.nextInt();

            boardGame[i] = new BoardGame (price, minPlayerNum, maxPlayerNum, genre, playTime);


        }
        for (int i = 0; i < boardGame.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(boardGame[i].toString());
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}


public class BoardGame {
    // Fields
    private String gameName;
    private String publisherName;
    private String yearPublished;
    private double price;
    private int minPlayerNum;
    private int maxPlayerNum;
    private String genre;
    private int playTime;

    // Constructor 1
    public BoardGame(String gameName, String publisherName, String yearPublished) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
        this.yearPublished = yearPublished;
    }

    // Constructor 2
    public BoardGame(double price, int minPlayerNum, int maxPlayerNum, String genre, int playTime) {
        this.price = price;
        this.minPlayerNum = minPlayerNum;
        this.maxPlayerNum = maxPlayerNum;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.playTime = playTime;
    }

    // Get Methods
    public String getGameName() {
        return gameName;
    }

    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }

    public String getYearPublished() {
        return yearPublished;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getMinPlayerNum() {
        return minPlayerNum;
    }

    public int getMaxPlayerNum() {
        return maxPlayerNum;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public int getPlayTime() {
        return playTime;
    }

    // Set Methods
    public void setGameName(String gameName) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
    }

    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }

    public void setYearPublished(String yearPublished) {
        this.yearPublished = yearPublished;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setMinPlayerNum(int minPlayerNum) {
        this.minPlayerNum = minPlayerNum;
    }

    public void setMaxPlayerNum(int maxPlayerNum) {
        this.maxPlayerNum = maxPlayerNum;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public void setPlayTime(int playTime) {
        this.playTime = playTime;
    }
    // Prints the data FIX_ME if min and max number of players is the same, only print one number
    public String toString() {
        return "Game name: " + gameName + "\nPublisher Name: " + publisherName + 
                "\nYear Published: " + yearPublished + "\nPrice: " + price + 
                "\nMinimum number of players: " + minPlayerNum + "\nMaximum number of players: "
                + maxPlayerNum + "\ngenre: " + genre + "\nPlay time: " + playTime;
    }

}
`
```

Depending on how I have it set up, either the first three won't have an assigned value, or the last 5 won't. It is currently set up in a way that makes the first three data pieces null.

Comment: What do you expect, for example, the game name to be if the second constructor is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second loop, instead of overriding the current `BoardGame` object by a new one like in your current code:

```
boardGame[i] = new BoardGame (price, minPlayerNum, maxPlayerNum, genre, playTime);
```

You should retrieve the `BoardGame` already stored in your array by the first loop, and call your setters on it:

```
boardGame[i].setPrice(price);
boardGame[i].setMinPLayerNum(minPlayerNum);
//etc...
```

Like so, you won't be overriding/replacing any values, you are just adding properties to the already created object.